# Propel Custom criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, propel

I'm trying to build the following query with propel critiera:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE facility_id IN (4,7)
GROUP BY housing_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT facility_id) = 2;
```

Propel Criteria:

```
$criteria->add(HousingsHousingFacilitiesPeer::HOUSING_FACILITY_ID, $facility_filter, Criteria::IN);

$criteria->addGroupByColumn(HousingsHousingFacilitiesPeer::HOUSING_ID);

$criteria->addHaving(
  $criteria->getNewCriterion(
    HousingsHousingFacilitiesPeer::HOUSING_ID, 
    'COUNT(DISTINCT housings_housing_facilities.HOUSING_FACILITY_ID) = 2',
    Criteria::CUSTOM
  )
);
```

But the query does net return any results.

Am I using the Custom criteria correctly?

Answer (score 1):

At first check, your `count distinct` seems wrong:

```
'COUNT(DISTINCT HousingsHousingFacilitiesPeer::HOUSING_FACILITY_ID) = 2'
```

If it's just a bad c/p, regarding [this snippet](http://snippets.symfony-project.org/snippet/257), you might do:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(HousingsHousingFacilitiesPeer::HOUSING_FACILITY_ID, $facility_filter, Criteria::IN);
$c->addGroupByColumn(HousingsHousingFacilitiesPeer::HOUSING_ID);
$c->addAsColumn('numFacilities', 'COUNT(DISTINCT '.HousingsHousingFacilitiesPeer::HOUSING_FACILITY_ID.')');
$c->addHaving($c->getNewCriterion(HousingsHousingFacilitiesPeer::ID, 'numArticles=2', Criteria::CUSTOM));
```